# Sinatra query collection

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm new to Sinatra and I'm trying to figure out how querying a collection in templates work.  In this particular example I'm trying to find out if in a specific collection (`c` in this example) of objects if there is an object with a certain value.

```
<% if c.votes #then filter by an id for example through all of the objects...  %>
    yes, it exists
<% else %>
    nope, doesn't exist
<% end %>
```

Also, I'm used to django's filters, is there a comparable documentation online that outlines the various query functions for Sinatra?

Comment: Are you using an ORM (AciveRecord, Sequel, etc.), or is `c` just a "regular" Ruby array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it just a standard collection?  You could use any?, which returns true if the provided block ever finds a match.  You would then test each object for the value you are looking for in that block.

```
<% if c.votes.any? { |a| a.id == whatever } %>
 ...
<% else %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

It really depends on what "votes" is.

Answer (score 1):

In rails you would use `<% if c.votes.present? %>` which is helpful because otherwise if c.votes is an empty array the condition would evaluate to true.

In Sinatra you don't have .present?, but you have a couple options: `<% unless c.vote.empty? %>` or `<% if !c.votes.empty %>`. I don't like the readability of either option, so I would recreate add the present? method to Array:

```
class Array
  def present?
    !empty?
  end
end
```

Where you add this depends on how you have your Sinatra app setup. One option would ti added it directly to your main app file.

Comment: I'm not looking to see only if there are objects within the collection, but more importantly if say any of the votes has the id of the current user associated with it.

Comment: You can have access to "present?" in sinatra. The method comes from activerecord  and not Rails